# Problem connecting to MongoDB Atlas cluster with mongoose (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, cluster-computing, mongodb-atlas

I've been struggling to connect to my mongodb atlas cluster through mongoose. I'm still fairly new to nodejs, but after searching around all I could find was to set the flag to
useNewUrlParser: true and my own compiler threw a warning for me to add useUnifiedTopology: true. However it keeps getting caught as an error. Thanks for any advice or direction

Update: when outputting err, i get

```
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

going to dig into this now

```
//THIS IS PART OF .ENV
ATLAS_URI=mongodb+srv://myusername:mypw@cluster(:idhere).mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority

//THIS IS PART OF SERVER.JS
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
// console.log('URI = "' + uri + '"'); //outputs correct URI

//without these two flags, get deprecated warning
mongoose.connect( uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('URI error'); //still goes into here
});
```

Comment: Using mongo cluster you need to specify what IP address have access to the database, or you can allow all ips through. Have a rummage around in your mongo cluster account there is a setting somewhere.

Comment: Please see [Configure Whitelist Entries](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/) for more information. If you still have issues connecting please add which MongoDB Node.JS driver version you're using.